# Can more than one Battle Master maneuver be used in the same attack?

Tags: dnd-5e, fighter, combat-maneuver

Some of the battle master maneuvers can be used whenever you make a weapon attack. My question is, could I use multiple superiority dice and do multiple maneuvers with a single strike?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

No, not with a "single strike", which the PHB would call an attack. Quoting from the Player's Handbook, p.73 (emphasis mine):

> Many maneuvers enhance an attack in some way. **You
>   can use only one maneuver per attack.**

If you have additional attacks, from a feat, from the Extra Attack class feature or from some other source, you can use one additional superiority die per attack to use more maneuvers within the same round.

Comment: It may be noteworthy that bonus actions used to attack would also qualify.

Comment: Yep. For the most part, the maneuvers themselves are specified to be triggered by "a weapon attack", "a melee attack", or "a melee weapon attack" (by you or by an enemy). This refers to a single attack (roll), not an Attack action - so if you have the Extra Attack feature, you can use multiple maneuvers per turn (assuming you have the superiority dice for it) if you take the Attack action and make the qualifying attacks, but you could only use one maneuver on each of the attacks that are part of that action.

Answer (score 11):

### No, in general...

*Player's Handbook*, p.73:

> You can use only one maneuver per attack.

---

### ...but Yes, in the case of Feinting Attack.

*Player's Handbook*, p.74:

> **Feinting Attack.** You can expend one superiority die and use a bonus action on your turn to feint, choosing one creature within 5 feet of you as your target.  You have advantage on your next attack roll against that creature.  If that attack hits, add the superiority die to the damage.

Given that the feint maneuver is used during the bonus action rather than during your next attack, it's possible to use Feinting Attack to "set up" a subsequent strike performed with some other Attack maneuver.  That strike will enjoy the benefits of both the feint and its own maneuver.

Comment: This still ends up as a two maneuvers on one attack. It's just that you're setting one of them up with a bonus action, but applying to the attack. I don't think the logic works out that they're different.